# Receiving question mark in java class from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, special-characters

I have a .jsp file that has a textarea, and when I recover the value of the textarea (in a Javascript function), the variable contains "importación" but when I send it to a java class and recover it, the variable contains "importaci?n"

I tried to do this, but it doesn't works:

in JSP:

```
var varValue = varExt.value.replace(/ó/g, "%F23");
```

and then in the Java class:

```
name = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8");
```

Does anyone have an idea as to what may be causing this?

**Finally I solved the problem adding URIEncoding="ISO-8859-15" to the tomcat connector.**

Comment: Are you using tomcat?

Comment: yes, I'm using tomcat v8.0

Comment: try adding URIEncoding="UTF-8" to the tomcat connector

Comment: Set URIEncoding to UTF-8 globally for the server you are working on.

Comment: `var varValue = varExt.value.replace(/\u00F3/g, "&#xF3;");` would be safer, as the JSP compiler and source code encodings may erroneously differ and still work. And the encoded thing must be either the entity above, or the correct %F3 (Latin-1 URL) or %C3%B3 (UTF-8 URL). (Though this is a patch, no regular solution.)

Comment: thank you very much to all, finaly I resolved adding URIEncoding="ISO-8859-15"

Comment: Apart from the URIEncoding, do I have to add anything else in some other file? because in some classes it decodes me well but in others it does not :(